# electric meter move advice

Tags: electrical, meter

I am carrying out some major driveway works soon, but would like advice on what to do with the electric meter.

The mains supply runs in the front of the property, goes into a garage there where the electric meter (Siemens S2AS) is located, and then carries on past the garage to supply electricity to the house.

So the garage is going to be knocked down, and a tarmac roadway put in it's place.  However I don't know what to do with the meter?  Once all the work is done I was thinking about having it in a small box or something near to the original location at the front of the property.

1. Should I move it to a temp location?  And can I do this myself, and get an electrical company to do a proper install later once I know where it's going?
2. Should I just get on and get the electrical company to move it to it's final resting place?  (not sure about this as the works are quite extensive and it could be in the way)
3. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Who do you have for an electric utility (DNO)?

Answer (score 5):

Things vary according to location but around here, you contact the local power company and request a temporary pole and disconnection of your current service.

Once that is done, you can complete your demolition and remodeling but the power company is going to expect to find a finished meter box that they can run the service drop lines to and then install and seal a meter for your new installation.  Then they will remove the temporary pole.

You are not authorized to mess with the always energized service drop wires on the company's side of the meter.

Answer (score 1):

Every power company has their own procedures for handling this. Here in Florida, you would have to contact the power company to have them transfer you service from your existing weatherhead to your temporary one. The temporary meter can and panel would be provided by you or your contractor. If you needed a pole set, the power company would charge you for it and you would be responsible for installing a meter can and panel.

Once your work was completed, the power company would come out and transfer your service from your temporary weather head to your newly installed (by you) weather head and set a new meter in the new can. They would then remove any poles you needed after you removed any weather heads and panels you had installed on them.